# Вывод переменной в документ

Tags: javascript

Ребят, помогите с JS
Почему в этом случае не работает вывод переменной? Нигде не могу найти документаций, но видел пример использования

```js
let name = prompt('Name: ', '');
document.write('Hello ${name}');
```

Answer (score 1):

Необходимо использовать [шаблонные строки](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings).

```js
const name = prompt('Name: ', '');
document.write(`Hello ${name}`);
```

Comment: Спасибо, не заметил)

Answer (score 1):

Для использования [шаблонных строк](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) строка должна быть обрамлена в обратные кавычки.

```js
let name = prompt('Name: ', '');
document.write(`Hello ${name}`);
```